# Is a high current wall charger dangerous for my phone?

Tags: usb, charger

I've bought a USB wall charger to power my Raspberry Pi. I chose the 3A one so that I can connect some more power hungly devices like hard drives to the Pi's USB ports.
I can connect 2 cables to the charger I bought.  I have two questions about it.

1. the charger that came with my Android is 1,2 A I think. Is it potentially harmfull to my phone if I charge it with my new charger since it is 3 A?
2. will I have a maximum of 3 A in total on the ports (so 2 * 1.5 for example), of will I have 3 A on each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Question 2 is unanswerable without disassembly of the charger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: No it is not harmful. Your phone will only draw the current it needs from the charger. As long as the charger voltage is right and it is rated to supply *at least* the current required by the device you will be fine.

Q2: Without a data sheet we don't know.

Edit:
The [power delivery specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Version_history_for_Power_related_specifications) indicate that 1.5 A was normal for battery charging with higher power available on later (2012) specifications. If it's a cheap PSU it might just have 5 V connected to each USB port without any current limiting at all, never mind individual port current limiting.

Comment: It didn't come with any datasheet. So both are possible? Both types exist (3A in total or 3A shared)?

Comment: See my update / edit.